# The caption of tables is not uppercase

Tags: captions, subcaption

I'm writing a paper using `Latex` with the `IEEEtran` package.

The preamble of the document is as follows:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage[pagewise, switch, mathlines]{lineno}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{color}

\def\hlinew#1{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xhline}

\newcommand{\lyxmathsym}[1]{\ifmmode\begingroup\def\b@ld{bold}
  \text{\ifx\math@version\b@ld\bfseries\fi#1}\endgroup\else#1\fi}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}

\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\else
  \usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\fi

\usepackage{stfloats}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\hyphenpenalty=3000
\hyphenation{pseudo-training}

\begin{document}

\title{Testing Caption}

\author{ABC}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Keywords
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle



\section{Introduction}
Introduction

\section{Experiments}

experiment 1

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Testing Caption.\label{tab:testing-table}}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

But the result is as follows:

[image]

The `Testing Caption` is not uppercase. Could you give some advice, please?

**UPDATED:**

I checked the `.log` file, there is indeed the following warning as @PaulGessler suggested.

```
   Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected (caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
   See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

**UPDATED**
Finally, with their kind suggestions in the answers, I find the problem is about the `subfigure` and `subfig`. In fact, when we use the `IEEEtran` package, it is not necessary to use the `caption` and `subcaption`. If we want to use `subfig`, we could use the following scripts(from the `IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf` in [https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/?lang=en]):

```
   \begin{figure*}[!t]
   \centering
   \subfloat[Case I]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{subf
    igcase1}
   \label{fig_first_case}}
   \hfil
   \subfloat[Case II]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{sub
   figcase2}
   \label{fig_second_case}}
   \caption{Simulation results for the network.}
   \label{fig_sim}
   \end{figure*}
```

And my original scripts is as follows:

```
      \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{fig1.eps}%
                \caption{Fig 1 caption}\label{fig:fig1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{fig2.eps}%
                \caption{Fig 2 caption}\label{fig:fig2}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Fig 1 and Fig 2}
        \label{fig:fig1_and_fig2}
    \end{figure}
```

which needs the `subfigure`, `caption` and `subcaption` packages. And the captions of tables are not uppercases, as a consequence, we have the problem in the post.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more, which part of the code you posted should make the text "Testing Caption" uppercase? Also, your posted code seems to be not a minimal working example as much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Please read your `.log` files, there's a warning there telling exactly the problem. The IEEE classes do a lot of modifications to the captions and the `caption`/`subcaption` packages don't know about this, so the modifications get overwritten. Don't use these packages with IEEE classes.

Comment: @BenediktBauer, thank you for suggestions! I've updated the post, please help check it. Because I use the same preamble in another paper, it could show uppercase caption in tables. I don't know why it doesn't work correctly in this document. I've tried several methods, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Hi, @PaulGessler, thank you for replying! I've checked the `.log` file, there is indeed a warning about `caption`. I've updated the post, please help check it. Thank you!

Comment: @mining what more is there to check? Comment out the `subcaption` and `caption` packages and the problem goes away!

Comment: @PaulGessler, because I use the `subfigure`, thus I must include the `caption` and `subcaption` packages in the main document.

Comment: @mining you already load the `subfig` package, which is currently recommended by IEEE for use with their classes when subfigures are needed. Multiple packages/classes mucking about with caption styling is a recipe for disaster, which is exactly what you have happening here.

Comment: @PaulGessler, thank you very much for suggestions. I might find the answers. I commented the `caption` and `subcaption` packages. And I read the `IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf` and replace the `subfigure` with `subfloat`, the styles of figure and tables are right. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by several packages for subfloats that interfere with each other and the documentclass's behaviour.

Comment: @BenediktBauer, thank you for replying! I'm very appreciated that you could allow me to keep this question. Because I think this might provide somebody else that an information about the `caption`, `subcaption`, `subfloat` and `subfigure`.

Comment: @mining Closing a question doesn't mean it will be deleted.

Comment: Hi, @cfr, thank you for replying and indicating my mistake. I'm sorry if I misunderstood. In other sites of stackoverflow, sometimes I post a question, someones would suggest me close the question. I thought they want me to delete it.

Comment: @mining No worries. It is confusing, I think. And questions which get deleted have to be closed first. It is just that most questions which get closed don't get deleted. For example, questions closed as duplicates are left as pointers to other questions as they often help people find things more easily.

Comment: Unrelated, but important: neither the `dvips` option to `graphicx` nor the `cmex10` option to `amsmath` should be given. Never ever. `:-)`

Comment: @cfr, OK, I see. Thank you for clarifying me!

Comment: @egreg, thank you for replying! But in fact I copy those commands from the last paper. Then I export this paper from `LyX` into the `plain Latex`, then I copy the main document into the latex framework of the last paper. But the problem is there. Then, I'm confused that why it worked in the last paper, but not in this paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of the `caption` (and its dependent `subcaption`) package is not supported when a class unknown to the package (such as IEEE) messes with caption styling. In the `.log` file, you get:

> ```
> Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
> (caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
> See the caption package documentation for explanation.
> ```

When these packages are used, the styling changes made by the class are overwritten. Commenting them out solves the issue at hand.

As for subfigures, you already have the code recommended by IEEE (see [`texdoc ieeetran`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ieeetran)), so just use the facilities of the `subfig` package for subfloats.

Multiple packages/classes messing about with caption styling is a recipe for disaster: even if you had been using a class supported by `caption`, you shouldn't use both `subcaption` and `subfig` at the same time. Packages with the same purpose are liable to have name clashes among other more subtle interactions. Just pick one and use that one only.

Comment: Thank you! I've confused several times about the `subfig`, `subfigure` and `subfloat`. And thank `tex.stackexchange.com` and the experts for providing me a lot of supports!